# Responsive grid in view layout

Tags: 7, views, theming

I think it's an easy question but I just can't solve it.

I use responsive grid type in view to show a content type named "clinic information",and it is.[image: clinic picture]

I want a row only have two clinics and the five-stars are beside the information(picture,phone number...), not below, how can I make it?

(picture, name, address, phone number, five-stars are clinic information in one content in a grid)

Comment: First of all what module are you using to render the responsive grid layout? This also depends on the type of theme you are using, are you using any one of the responsive themes, e.g. bootstrap? The solution can very simple like overriding the output markup of the view with something to your liking. That is what I usually do. Provide the additional info and I will post a full answer for you.

Comment: Sorry for that I just use drupal for a week so many things I probably can't understand.

The theme I used is CorporateClean, and modules that I'm using are Views Responsive Grid(using CSS), Fivestar and Views only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing to make this work is the theme that your using; the [Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/Views_Responsive_Grid) doesn't do much by itself with regards to styling but it allows you setup you view to apply the appropriate CSS class from your theme to make your display responsive.

You are using the [Corporate Clean](https://www.drupal.org/project/corporateclean) theme but it's not a truly responsive theme from what I can see from its [layout CSS](https://github.com/morethanthemes/corporateclean/blob/master/site/sites/all/themes/corporateclean/css/basic-layout.css). You can still have that layout that you want for one screen type so that will be what I will show you here.

1. Change your view's format to **Responsive Grid**
   [image]
2. Next change the settings for the **Responsive Grid** format to have  2 column in horizontal alignment and the class `grid_6` to every column. You can also use `grid_4` if you have a sidebar on your page.
   [image]
3. Then change the Format's **Show** options to fields.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Now in the fields section add all the fields that you want to display. For example, I have the fields title, body and post date.
   [image]

The next step requires you to add some custom html/css; normally advanced view display formats such as [Views Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) would have different options to display your fields. For example, had you been using a Bootstrap based theme the [Media Object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) format would have served you well.

However, since you are using something different, I would recommend you override the out of the fields as follows.

5. Hide all but the last one of your fields by clicking on each field and checking the "Exclude from display option". 
   [image]
6. For the last field override its display by clicking on it and going to the **Rewrite Results** section. In the text box provided add in your custom HTML markup with along your fields using tokens provided by views.
   [image]
7. In you theme make sure to add proper CSS classes, i.e, in the example HMTL I'm showing you should have the classes `clinic`, `clinic-thumb` and `clinic-details`. These should have the styling in such a ways that the `clinic` class clear floats, the `clinic-thumb` and `clinic-details` classes should have floats and respective widths. 
   Example CSS:

   /**

   - .clinic has a clearfix taken from [this page](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) 
     */

   .clinic:before,
   .clinic:after {
       content: " "; /* 1 */
       display: table; /* 2 */
   }
   .clinic:after {
       clear: both;
   }
   /**

   - For IE 6/7 only
     */
     .clinic {
     *zoom: 1;
     }

   .clinic-thumb{
    width: 35%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    float: left;
   }
   .clinic-details{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
   }

If you followed my example you should get something like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it almost works for me, but there's last one problem that it only has one column. 
[screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/TdHv9)

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with the class you used, did you use the `grid_6`? Please try with the `grid_4` classes.

Comment: When I try [grid4](https://imgur.com/a/Hh23q), it become [so](https://imgur.com/a/nne9j).

Comment: Oh I see, maybe you can try to revert back to `grid_6` and make sure that you don't have any padding and/or margin to the div with the `grid_6` class. If there is padding or margin added to the div it will go down to the next line; maybe that would have been the problem. Do you have the site live somewhere? I can look at it give you a suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I change classes into [this](http://imgur.com/a/uLgRt) and it becomes [normal](https://imgur.com/a/NJ7r0), I don't know how it works but it does.

Comment: Well if it works for you then that's good!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create CSS rules for the output. To make it responsive and fluid, use percentage value instead of pixel value.

**Grid 3:**

`.views-column {
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
}`

**Grid 4:**

`.views-column {
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
}`

To switch the 4-column and 3-column to 2-column on view port width when it is less than 600px:

`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* change Grid 4 to 2-column */
    .views-column {
        width: 48.4%;
    }
    .views-column:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
        margin-left: 2%;
        clear: none;
    }
    .views-column:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
        margin-left: 0;
        clear: left;
    }
    /* change Grid 3 to 2-column */
    .views-column {
        width: 48.4%;
    }
    .views-column:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
        margin-left: 3.2%;
        clear: none;
    }
    .views-column:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
        margin-left: 0;
        clear: left;
    }
}`